# Java: For loop print statement for two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to do a two dimensional for loop that with print this:

7   5   3   1

2   4   6   8

Here is my array:

```
int [][] secondArray = {{7, 5, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 6, 8}};
```

The for loop below will only print it one number after the other. Not all on one straight line. I have tried playing around with it. Like making two print statements. On for i and j. Or doing a "\t". I'm just learning arrays and this for loop was the closest example I got online.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < secondArray.length ; i++)
     {

            for(int j = 0; j < secondArray[i].length; j++)
            {

                System.out.println(secondArray[i][j]);

            }

     }
```

Edit: I guess I should put that I understand how for loops work. It goes through each number and prints it. I guess my question is, how else would I do this?

Comment: Use System.out.print instead of System.out.println, also loop is not two dimensional, the array is two dimensional, and to iterate that array you are using two nested loops.

Comment: Ah thanks... An obvious beginner mistake that I wasn't even thinking about. I thought my problem lied much deeper!

Comment: It should look something like this: https://pastebin.com/wiKPCJTW

Comment: `The for loop below will only print it one number after the other. Not all on one straight line`  then it should be `System.out.print(secondArray[i][j] + " ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println() if you don't want to the next output to be from next line.

**Code**

```
for(int i = 0; i < secondArray.length ; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < secondArray[i].length; j++) {
         System.out.print(secondArray[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach loop and print a line everytime you jump from one inner array to another:

```
for(int[] a : secondArray) {
      for(int b : a) {
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(' ');
      }
      System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works..

```
  int [][] secondArray = {{7, 5, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 6, 8}};

     for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length ; i++)
     {

         for(int j = 0; j < secondArray[i].length; j++)
         {
             System.out.print(secondArray[i][j]);
             System.out.print(' ');

       }

         System.out.println();
     }
```